# Using crontab to call wget every 5 minutes

Tags: php, symfony, cron, wget

I am working on a project where the `wget` and `crontab` are used to run a process in the background. I have a `php` file named "Hello.php" that I want to run this every 5 minutes. I have found that if I want to have a cron job run every 5 minutes, I should use the following `crontab` entries :

```
*/5 * * * root wget ..... # Other processes run as such
* * * * * root wget https://hello.com/cron/advertise
```

How can I link my "Hello.php" class with `cron` to run in every 5 minutes? 
I am using `symfony2`.

Comment: Fix grammar and code highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [console component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

make it run your hello.php script

call the command in your crontab

`bash /your/dir/app/console yourcommand`

or even simpler run `php your/dir/hello.php`